# C# and F# casting - specifically the 'as' keyword

Tags: c#, f#, c#-to-f#

In C# I can do:

```
var castValue = inputValue as Type1
```

In F#, I can do:

```
let staticValue = inputValue :> Type1
let dynamicValue = inputValue :?> Type1
```

But neither of them is the equivalent of the C#'s keyword `as`.

I guess I need to do a match expression for the equivalent in F#

```
match inputValue with
| :? Type1 as type1Value -> type1Value
| _ -> null
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As far as I know, F# doesn't have any built-in operator equivalent to C# `as` so you need to write some more complicated expression. Alternatively to your code using `match`, you could also use `if`, because the operator `:?` can be use in the same way as `is` in C#:

```
let res = if (inputValue :? Type1) then inputValue :?> Type1 else null
```

You can of course write a function to encapsulate this behavior (by writing a simple generic function that takes an `Object` and casts it to the specified generic type parameter):

```
let castAs<'T when 'T : null> (o:obj) = 
  match o with
  | :? 'T as res -> res
  | _ -> null
```

This implementation returns `null`, so it requires that the type parameter has `null` as a proper value (alternatively, you could use `Unchecked.defaultof<'T>`, which is equivalent to `default(T)` in C#). Now you can write just:

```
let res = castAs<Type1>(inputValue)
```

Comment: This works if the type is static. Any idea what to do if the type is defined at runtime? I'm looking for a F# equivalent of http://stackoverflow.com/a/19068042/23059.

Answer (score 14):

I would use an active pattern.  Here is the one I use:

```
let (|As|_|) (p:'T) : 'U option =
    let p = p :> obj
    if p :? 'U then Some (p :?> 'U) else None
```

Here is a sample usage of `As`:

```
let handleType x = 
    match x with
    | As (x:int) -> printfn "is integer: %d" x
    | As (s:string) -> printfn "is string: %s" s
    | _ -> printfn "Is neither integer nor string"

// test 'handleType'
handleType 1
handleType "tahir"
handleType 2.
let stringAsObj = "tahir" :> obj
handleType stringAsObj
```

Comment: This is unnecessary... as the original question notes, F# pattern matching has this built in. You can `| :? int as i -> i`.

Comment: is this functionally any different than using `| :?` as @DanFitch suggests?

Comment: found a majorly useful difference. you can do Post-cast sub-matching without a when clause. `function |As(Some true) -> () | _ -> ()` for instance

Comment: Note that post-cast matching is now possible in F# 6 (https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-design/blob/main/FSharp-6.0/FS-1105-Non-variable-patterns-to-the-right-of-as-patterns.md), so you should really use the built-in syntax as @DanFitch mentions

Answer (score 6):

You can create your own operator to do this.  This is virtually identical to Tomas's example, but shows a slightly different way to call it.  Here's an example:

```
let (~~) (x:obj) = 
  match x with
  | :? 't as t -> t //'
  | _ -> null

let o1 = "test"
let o2 = 2
let s1 = (~~o1 : string)  // s1 = "test"
let s2 = (~~o2 : string) // s2 = null
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes; see, except below from:
[What does this C# code look like in F#? (part one: expressions and statements)](https://lorgonblog.wordpress.com/2008/11/28/what-does-this-c-code-look-like-in-f-part-one-expressions-and-statements/)

> C# has "is" and "as" operators for type tests.  F# uses a particular pattern in a match for this.  So this C# code:

```cs
    if (animal is Dog)
    {
        Dog dog = animal as Dog;
        // …
    }
    else if (animal is Cat)
    {
        Cat cat = animal as Cat;
        // …
    }
```

> becomes this F# code:

```
    match animal with
    | :? Dog as dog -> // …
    | :? Cat as cat -> // …
```

> where ":? type" is a type test, and "as ident" names the resulting value of that type if the type test succeeds.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer link only answer, not to another stackoverflow detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I guess I need to do a match expression for the equivalent in F#
>
> `match inputValue with
>   | :? Type1 as type1Value -> type1Value
>   | _ -> null`
>
> Is this correct?

Yes, it's correct. (Your own answer is better than the rest of the answers in my opinion.)