# How to determine if an object is a certain type in F#

Tags: f#

in C# I could use the keyword 'is'

```
if (variable is string)
{
}
```

how is this done in f#

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try

```
if (variable :? string) ...
```

or

```
let x = variable :? string
```

Comment: What about C# `as` operator equivalent?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361851/c-sharp-and-f-casting-specifically-the-as-keyword @Andrii