# When pattern matching for types doesn't work

Tags: android, f#, pattern-matching

I am using a guard within a pattern matching expression in lieu of the C# `as` operator. The problem is, it doesn't seem to be doing what I expect it to do.

Here is the code snippet:

```
open Android.Gms.Vision.Faces

type GraphicFaceTracker(logger: ILog, createImageAnalyser: Func<byte[], IImageAnalyser>, overlay: NativeGraphicOverlay, preview: NativeCameraSourcePreview, cameraSource: CameraSource) =
    inherit Tracker()
    let mutable isProcessing = false
    let faceGraphic = new FaceGraphic(overlay)
    override this.OnNewItem(id, item) =
        match item with
        | :? Face as face -> 
            overlay.Add faceGraphic
            faceGraphic.UpdateFace face
        | _ ->
            0 |> ignore
```

When I stop the program in the debugger, the code is hitting the `0 |> ignore` line, and not the useful overlay line. But when I look at the value of `item`, it is an instance of `Android.Gms.Vision.Faces.Face`. What could possibly be going wrong here?

To fix this in the short term, I am going to try using an active pattern (as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25243799/1002908) answer), but at this point I'm more keen to understand why it's going wrong than in fixing the immediate problem.

**UPDATE**:

The solution that works best is

```
if (item :? Face) then
    overlay.Add faceGraphic
    let face = (item :> obj) :?> Face
    faceGraphic.UpdateFace face
```

Although not particularly functional, it has the virtue of actually doing what I expect it to do. The mystery of why the pattern matching seems to fail still remains, though.

Comment: Is there a naming collision, i.e. does `:? Android.Gms.Vision.Faces.Face as ...` resolve the issue?

Comment: FYI: "0 |> ignore" could be replaced with "()"

Comment: I think you have the casing of `face` wrong. I would expect it to be `:? face as Face`, where `face` is the name and `Face` the type.

Comment: Thanks Foole. F# is always full of little surprises.

Comment: Matiasd -- it sounds to me like you're still in C# territory. Can you show me a snippet to demonstrate?

Comment: Yeah, I got it wrong. My test example produced the "correct" answer for the wrong reasons.

Comment: No worries. My example is still failing inexplicably. Funk's suggestion (giving the fully qualified class name) didn't work either. I've reverted to a straightforward `if` statement, which may not be very functional, but has the distinct advantage of actually working.

Comment: (1) how exactly do you "look in the debugger". I mean, how do you check the type of `item`? (2) are you sure that the useful branch is not actually executing? Have you tried adding debug print there or something similar?

Comment: (1) I'm using the watch window in VS 2017, and entering `item` and `item.GetType()`. (2) It is definitely not executing.