# Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject'

Tags: c#, outlook

[image]

[image]When I am a casting below code then i got an error

Code :

```
string subject = ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)myInbox.Items[temp])
    .Subject.ToString();
```

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface
>   type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem'. This operation
>   failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the
>   interface with IID '{00063034-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due
>   to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

Comment: What is the rest of the error message?

Comment: "No such interface" I think

Comment: now u can see the full error message

Comment: Can you try to get the actual com type of myInbox.Items[temp] by checking [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429548/how-to-get-type-of-com-object)

Comment: [System.RuntimeType] = {Name = "__ComObject" FullName = "System.__ComObject"} means its change the runtime type system._ComObject

Comment: The inbox can contain more than just mail items.  Use the `as` operator to skip the ones you don't like.

Comment: no inbox not contain more mail items the mail which have auto response that type of mail gives the error you can see the mail which gives the error in highlighted by red box you can see in the attachment.

Comment: Before you go any further: what are you trying to do? I see you're writing an ASPX page. Please note that that code will **not** interact with the visitor's Outlook.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what Hans said - it's not a `MailItem`. You need to skip the inbox items that aren't `MailItem`s.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to cast COM object - Microsoft outlook & C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656360/unable-to-cast-com-object-microsoft-outlook-c-sharp)

Answer (score 4):

You need to check the item type first. Outlook folders may contain various types of items:

```
Object selObject = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
        if (selObject is Outlook.MailItem)
        {
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem =
                (selObject as Outlook.MailItem);
            itemMessage = "The item is an e-mail message." +
                " The subject is " + mailItem.Subject + ".";
            mailItem.Display(false);
        }
        else if (selObject is Outlook.ContactItem)
        {
            Outlook.ContactItem contactItem =
                (selObject as Outlook.ContactItem);
            itemMessage = "The item is a contact." +
                " The full name is " + contactItem.Subject + ".";
            contactItem.Display(false);
        }
        else if (selObject is Outlook.AppointmentItem)
        {
            Outlook.AppointmentItem apptItem =
                (selObject as Outlook.AppointmentItem);
            itemMessage = "The item is an appointment." +
                " The subject is " + apptItem.Subject + ".";
        }
        else if (selObject is Outlook.TaskItem)
        {
            Outlook.TaskItem taskItem =
                (selObject as Outlook.TaskItem);
            itemMessage = "The item is a task. The body is "
                + taskItem.Body + ".";
        }
        else if (selObject is Outlook.MeetingItem)
        {
            Outlook.MeetingItem meetingItem =
                (selObject as Outlook.MeetingItem);
            itemMessage = "The item is a meeting item. " +
                 "The subject is " + meetingItem.Subject + ".";
        }
```

See [How to: Programmatically Determine the Current Outlook Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268994.aspx) for more information.

Comment: I have request read receipt type outlook mail in my inbox and i want to read that particular mail from c#

Answer (score 0):

```
string subject = myInbox.Items[temp])
    .Subject.ToString();
```

There is no need to cast frist check that myinbox object have subject property in not string then you need to cast it if it is string formate then don't need to cast it.