# Casting elements of `GroupItems` to `Shape`

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a grouped shape in a document:

```vb
Dim doc As Word.Document
Set doc = Documents("dlr-overview.docx")
Dim firstShape As Word.Shape
Set firstShape = doc.Shapes(1)
```

`AutoShapeType` on `firstShape` returns `-2`, or `msoShapeMixed`; and `firstShape.GroupItems.Count` returns `25`:

```
Debug.Print firstShape.AutoShapeType
Debug.Print firstShape.GroupItems.Count
```

I can iterate over the shapes in `firstShape.GroupItems` without casting to `Shape`. `TypeName` returns `"Shape"` for each element, and the `AutoShapeType` property returns `5`, or `msoShapeRoundedRectangle`:

```vb
Dim x As Variant
For Each x In firstShape.GroupItems
    Debug.Print TypeName(x)
    Debug.Print x.AutoShapeType
Next
```

But when I try to cast each element to `Shape`, I get **Type mismatch** on the first iteration of the `For Each`:

```vb
Dim subshape As Shape
For Each subshape In firstShape.GroupItems
    Debug.Print subshape.Left
Next
```

How can I extract information about an individual shape from the grouped shape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is impossible to enumerate using a [**Shape**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.shape) variable over the [**GroupShapes**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.groupshapes) object returned from [**Shape.GroupItems**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.shape.groupitems). The following also errors within the iteration:

```vb
Dim shapes As GroupShapes
Set shapes = firstShape.GroupItems
Dim shp As Shape
For Each shp In shapes
    Debug.Print shp.Name
Next
```

Apparently the returned elements are something other than [**Word.Shape**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.shape) objects, even though the [**TypeName**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/typename-function) function returns `"Shape"` for such objects.

However, if I access the elements via the [**Item**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.groupshapes.item) property of the **GroupShapes** collection, or via the default property, they are returned as [**Word.Shape**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.shape) objects, and can be casted to [**Word.Shape**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.shape):

```vb
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To firstShape.GroupItems.Count
    Dim shp As Shape
    Set shp = firstShape.GroupItems(i)
    Debug.Print shp.Name
Next
```